# How to warn user before session timeout ends in javascript?

Tags: javascript, session

I am coming to a minor problem where I have a session timeout in my `web.xml` for 15 minutes. But, in javascript I tried to warn the user for 5 minutes before it hits 15 minutes, but when it warns the user and the  user clicks on OK, then the web app won't work anymore. All I want to do is warn the user about there session timeout and then when they press ok, they can still use the web app. Yet, when there session timeout times up, I want them to click on OK and takes them to a different web page. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem to solve. What I do is send back with every HTTP response instructions for the client to restart the session timer. The timer should be run such that it wakes up every second and checks the time; you have to deal with browsers slowing down timers. Exactly how you set it up depends on the nature of your application.

Comment: Keep in mind that opening multiple tabs/windows to your website, sets multiple timers with different expiration times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: When you want to warn the user 5 minutes before the 15 minutes timeout, the warning shoud be displayed at 10 minutes after page load.

```
setTimeout( function() { alert("Your session will expire in 5 minutes."); }, 10*60*1000);
```

If you want to redirect the user after 15 minutes to a different page, you don't actually need the user to confirm this.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = "timeout.xhtml";
}, 15*60*1000);
```

## So, when does the timeout actually happen?

With multiple tabs your user could just use the app in 2 tabs. The actions in the second tab will keep the app from timing out. One way is to reload the page and let the server handle the timeout and redirection part. Another option (preferred one) is to periodically check, whether the session still exists. Be aware: Your session checking should not extend the timeout period.

Comment: ok. That mean, I don't need my else statement, I can just apply it with just `setTimeout` ?

Comment: Given that the session has already expired and you want to display the timeout, there is no meaning in keeping the current page. So no `else` neccessary.

Comment: In any case, if the answer satisfies your question, please accept it.